# reading data from localStorage does not render in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state, rendering

I have a MenuComponent.js component which brings me data from an API and draws the products through a map.

```
import ProductCard from './Cards/ProductCard'
import {Container, Row, Col, Button} from 'react-bootstrap'
import '../styles/MenuComponent.css'



const MenuComponent = () => {

    const [cart, setCart] = useState([])

    const addToCart = (product) =>{
        setCart([...cart, product])      
    }

    const [productos, setProductos] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        getProducts();
        localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart));
    },[cart])

    const getProducts = async() => {
        try {
            const res = await fetch('https://my-json-server.typicode.com/Fawkes11/FAKE_API_services/menu');
            const data = await res.json();
            setProductos(data);
          } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
          }
    }
    return (
        <Container fluid className="menuComponentContainer p-5">
            <Row style={{paddingLeft: '150px', paddingRight: '150px'}}>
                <Col style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent:'center'}}>
                    <h2>Menú</h2>
                </Col>
                <Col style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent:'center'}}>
                    <Button className='productCardButton'>
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" className="bi bi-download me-2" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                        <path d="M.5 9.9a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v2.5a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h12a1 1 0 0 0 1-1v-2.5a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0v2.5a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H2a2 2 0 0 1-2-2v-2.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5z"/>
                        <path d="M7.646 11.854a.5.5 0 0 0 .708 0l3-3a.5.5 0 0 0-.708-.708L8.5 10.293V1.5a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v8.793L5.354 8.146a.5.5 0 1 0-.708.708l3 3z"/>
                        </svg>
                        Descargar
                    </Button>
                </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row style={{marginTop: '20px'}}>
                {
                    productos.map((pro) => {
                        return(
                            <Col className='cElementsMenu' key={pro.id}>
                                {cart.length}
                                <ProductCard
                                addToCart={addToCart}
                                id={pro.id}
                                photo={pro.imagen}
                                name={pro.product}
                                type={pro.type}
                                size={pro.tamaño}
                                price={pro.precio}
                                />
                            </Col> 
                        )
                    })
                }             
            </Row>
        </Container>
    )
}

export default MenuComponent;
```

Next the ProductCard.jsx component which is the structure of each product.

```
import {Card, Button} from 'react-bootstrap'
import '../../styles/productCard.css'




const ProductCard = (props) => {

    const [hover, setHover] = useState(false);

    return (
        
        <Card className='productCard' style={{ width: '18rem', borderRadius: '20px' }}>
            <div
                className='productOverflow'
                onMouseEnter={() => setHover(true)}
                onMouseLeave={() => setHover(false)}
            >
                {hover && <Button className='buttonPreviewProduct'>Vista previa</Button>}
                <Card.Img
                className={`productCardImg ${hover && 'hover'}`}
                variant="top"
                src={props.photo}
                />
            </div>

            <Card.Body className='productCardBody'>
                <Card.Title className='productCardtitle'>{props.name} {props.type}</Card.Title>
                <Card.Text>$ {props.price}</Card.Text>
                <Button className='productCardButton' onClick={() => props.addToCart(props)}>Agregar al carrito</Button>
            </Card.Body>
        </Card>
    )
}

export default ProductCard;
```

now the problem, when adding to the cart it works fine and it even reflects the amount of products added, but when adding them to the LocalStorage and then trying to read them from the next component it does not render automatically, I have to update the page (F5) to make it look reflected my product account.

CartCounterIcon.jsx

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { getCartItems } from '../../modules/cart'

function CartCounterIcon(props) {

    return (
        <div style={countIcon.div}><p style={countIcon.p}>{getCartItems().length}</p></div>
    )
}

const countIcon = {
    div: {
        margin: '0',
        padding: '0px 6px',
        position: 'absolute',
        right: '0',
        top: '0',
        backgroundColor: '#91491a',
        borderRadius: '20%',
    },
    p: {
        margin: '0',
        color: '#eadac0',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
    }
    
}


export default CartCounterIcon
```

the following is the function that I import to get the data from localStorage. the problem is not saving them, the problem is that when reading the local data they do not render the CartCounterIcon.jsx component. Thanks in advance for your help

cart.js

```
export function getCartItems(){
    const data = localStorage.getItem("cart");
    if(!data) return [];
    return JSON.parse(data);
}
```

Comment: There is nothing in your code to indicate you're using local storage.

Comment: already update :3